# How can I print label if the corresponding function is called in the console.log. Now its not printing the label and result?

Tags: javascript

How can I print label if the corresponding function is called in the console.log. Now its not printing the label and result ?  Can someone please advise

```
    let num1 = 100;
    let num2 = 200;
    let text = 'add';
    calculationOfNumbers(text, num1, num2);
    
    function calculationOfNumbers(text, num1, num2) {
    if (text == 'add') {
        let label = "Adding";
        let result = addFunction(num1, num2);
        console.log(`This is : ${label}`+result);
    } else if (text == 'subtract') {
        let label = "Subtracting";
        let result = subtractFunction(num1, num2);
        console.log(`This is : ${label}`+result);
    }

}

function addFunction(num1, num2 ) {
    let result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
    return result;
}

function subtractFunction(num1, num2) {
    let result = parseInt(num2)  - parseInt(num1) ;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript supports returning a single value. That value must be captured at the point of the function call if you want to do anything with it. A tutorial might be a good place to start.

Comment: @DaveNewton I have understood my mistake , but I would like know is there a way not to write declare the label and console log twice .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those `return label, result` does nothing. It is the same as doing `return result`. Learn about *comma operator*. There's no tuple data type in JS yet.

What you could do instead is the following:

```js
function addFunction(num1, num2, label) {
    let result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
    return [label, result];
}
```

```js
function calculationOfNumbers(x, num1, num2) {
    let label, result;
    if (x == 'add') {
       [label, result] = addFunction(num1, num2, "adding");
    } else if (x == 'subtract') {
       [label, result] = subtractFunction(num1, num2, "subtracting");
    }
    console.log(`This is : ${label} ${result}`);
}
```

ie., return arrays and use destructuring.

Or even:

```js
function calculationOfNumbers(x, num1, num2) {
    let result;
    if (x == 'add') {
       result = addFunction(num1, num2);
    } else if (x == 'subtract') {
       result = subtractFunction(num1, num2);
    }
    console.log(`This is: ${label} ${result}`);
}

function addFunction(num1, num2) {
    let result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
    return label="adding", result;
}

function subtractFunction(num1, num2) {
    let result = parseInt(num2)  - parseInt(num1) ;
    return label="subtracting", result;
}
```

(I'm not saying this is the best approach tho)

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot return multiple values with one `return` statement in JavaScript, one option you could use is to instead return an `object` like so:

```js
let total = 0;
let num1 = 100;
let num2 = 200;
let text = 'add';
let label = "";

calculationOfNumbers(text, num1, num2);

function calculationOfNumbers(x, num1, num2) {
    let info;

    if (x == 'add') {
        info = addFunction(num1, num2, "adding");
    } else if (x == 'subtract') {
        info = subtractFunction(num1, num2, "subtracting");
    }

    console.log(`This is ${info.label} : ${info.result}`);
}

function addFunction(num1, num2, label) {
    let result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
    return { label, result };
}

function subtractFunction(num1, num2, label) {
    let result = parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1);
    return { label, result };
}
```

Notice how I assign each function call to the variable `info` then you can access the required properties with `info.label` and `info.results`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

there are few things needs to be amended in your code

```js
 function calculationOfNumbers(x, num1, num2) {
    if (x == 'add') {
        // function is returning some values, but it was never stored somewhere to be used later
        addFunction(num1, num2, "adding");
    } else if (x == 'subtract') {
      // same situation, function is returning some values, but it was never stored somewhere to be used later
        subtractFunction(num1, num2, "subtracting");
    }
   // you are printing (result) but it was never declared before
    console.log(`This is : ${label}`+result);
}

function addFunction(num1, num2, label) {
  // it's better to use Number(num1) instead of parseInt()
    let result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
    // you are returning label inside here, however you didn't amend the global variable result,
// also no need to pass it down to this function, the add function should be returning only the result of the calculation
    return label, result;
}

function subtractFunction(num1, num2, label) {
    let result = parseInt(num2)  - parseInt(num1) ;
    return label, result;
}
```

So the code after amendment should look like below:

```js
let num1 = 100;
let num2 = 200;
let text = 'add';

calculationOfNumbers(text, num1, num2);

function calculationOfNumbers(x, num1, num2) {
  let label = x;
  let result = 0;

  if (x == 'add') {
    result = addFunction(num1, num2);
  } else if (x == 'subtract') {
    result = subtractFunction(num1, num2);
  }
  console.log(`This is : ${label}` + result);
}

function addFunction(num1, num2) {
  let result = Number(num1) + Number(num2);
  return result;
}

function subtractFunction(num1, num2) {
  let result = Number(num2) - Number(num1);
  return result;
}
```